# Application error. The application was unable to start correctly (0x000007b).Click Ok to close the application

Tags: windows, dllimport

Can somebody help with the following error please?

```
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\wsock32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ws2_32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nsi.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Suneel\Keyboard\WidgetKeyboard\Debug glsdll md\iconv.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'WidgetKeyboard.exe': Loaded 'C:\Suneel\Keyboard\WidgetKeyboard\Debug glsdll md\zlib1.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
The program '[6452] WidgetKeyboard.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741701 (0xc000007b).
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't give us much to start from. Apparently you are using `DllImport` in .NET (I guessed that from the tag, correct me if I'm wrong).

`0xc000007b` means  STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT, and you are probably trying to load a 32-bit image into a 64 process or vice versa.

Usually, Windows tries to prevent that from ever happening. File system virtualization ensures that DLL loads from C:\Windows\system32 are redirected to C:\Windows\syswow64, and Registry virtualization ensures that COM servers are matched with the bit-ness of the COM client.

There's probably something that you did that bypasses these counter-measures. Maybe you copied DLLs to the same folder as your EXE. Or the resolution of the DLL path goes wrong, e.g. because you rely on the system's PATH environment variable or you used `SetDllDirectory()`.

First of all, check that the bit-ness of your application matches the bitness of the DLL you are importing. If that fails, use SysInternals' ProcMon, which shows you what file it is trying to load.

Comment: I've used the right bit of libraries the problem I'm seeing is with libiconv Whenever my program is been run it is asking to locate iconv.dll,have downloaded the 64 bit libraries from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/?source=typ_redirect and have placed the .dll with the right naming as .iconv.dll and while running am seeing this error. The only thing I might have to now do is "http://www.bitdefender.com/files/KnowledgeBase/file/dlls_x64.zip" replace these files...that is the only option seems left, please suggest

Comment: Is your own process 64-bit? Have you checked Process Monitor? Has the downloaded version the correct bitness? What happens if you place the correct version of the DLL on your system instead manually instead of downloading?

Comment: Yes mine is a 64 bit process, also have run dependency walker, the only error I could see in dependency walker is "IESHIMS.DLL - Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified (2)", downloaded version of iconv.dll is correct or not I couldn't validate it, may I know how to validate if it is 32bit/64bit? Also not sure "What happens if you place the correct version of the DLL on your system instead manually instead of downloading? " how to do this...sorry for more queries as I am new to debuggin in Windows, I have got only Linux debugging skills using gdb

Comment: Yours appears to be a 32 bit process according to the info in the question

Answer (score 0):

That is an `NTSTATUS` error code. Look it up here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc704588.aspx

In your case `0xC000007B` is `STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT`. Described like this:

> {Bad Image} %hs is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.

Typically that means that the loader, when resolving load-time dependencies, is attempting to load a 64 bit DLL into a 32 bit process, or vice versa. The diagnostics you show suggest that your process is a 32 bit process. So you should look for the 64 bit DLL that the loader is attempting to load. Use the Dependency Walker tool in Profile mode to debug this.